# How do i refresh functions on page resize in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, require

[DEMO :](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/uo34ddu6/) 
i have a set of functions being used in RWD,

The issue I'am facing is every time i have to refresh the page to run the functions, is there a way to **REFRESH FUNCTIONS** . 
iam using bootstrap, require.js

can someone shed some light on this, the functions why iam refreshing is because of custom components.

sample code :

```
$(function () {

                function toggleNavbarMethod() {
                    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
                        $('nav .score-megamenu-dropdown').on('mouseover', function () {
                            $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
                        }).on('mouseout', function () {
                            $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click').blur();
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        $('nav .score-megamenu-dropdown').off('mouseover').off('mouseout');
                    }
                }
                toggleNavbarMethod();
                $(window).resize(toggleNavbarMethod);


                var PGBRAUN = PGBRAUN || {};

                PGBRAUN = {
                    globalVars: {
                        onPageLoad: '',
                        MD_min_width: 992,
                        XS_max_width: 767,
                        SM_min_width: 768,
                        SM_max_width: 991
                    },
                    domReady: function () {
                        $('.mob-header').parent('.container').hide(); // hiding sign in and signup container in dt 
                    },
                    preventLinks: function () {
                        /* anything needed to run at DOM load (not page load) would be declared here */
                        var stopFromLinking = ".score-header ul.header-category li:first-child, .score-footer ul.footer-social-share li:first-child, a.menu-links";
                        $(document).on('click', stopFromLinking, function (e) {
                            e.preventdefault();
                        })
                    },
                    megaMenuSP: function () {
                        if ($(window).width() < 991) {
                            /* Changing Menu slide-collapse attribute on ready */
                            $('.score-hamburger.navbar-toggle').attr('data-toggle', 'slide-collapse');

                            /* Adding of new div for slide container starts*/
                            $('.score-header').after($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
                            $(".mob-header, .navbar-collapse").wrapAll("<div id='slidemenu'></div>");
                            //$('html .mob-header').prependTo('.navbar-collapse');

                            var slidewidth = '80%';
                            var navbarneg = '-' + slidewidth;

                            /* Adding of new div for slide container ends*/

                            $('#navbar-height-col').css({
                                "width": slidewidth,
                                "right": navbarneg
                            });

                            $('#slidemenu').css({
                                "width": '86.7%',
                                "right": navbarneg
                            });
                            $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
                            $('.page-wrapper').attr('id', 'page-content');
                            navVisible = 0;

                            /* Main Menu Button Hamburger starts */
                            $(document).on('click', '.navbar-toggle', function (e) {
                                //debugger;   
                                /* Show Close Icon starts */
                                $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
                                $(this).toggleClass('collapsed').attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
                                /* Show Close Icon ends */

                                /* Hiding Images from Ul dd start  */
                                $('ul.dropdown-menu').find('.header-mega-menu-view-all-button, .header-mega-menu-img').hide();
                                /* Hiding Images from Ul dd ends  */

                                /* Adding Class for Mobile View starts -> check can this be added on load */
                                $('.score-megamenu-dropdown').find('.menu-links').addClass('dropdown-toggle toggle-caret button-caret').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown');
                                /* Adding Class for Mobile View ends */

                                /* Finding Mob Sign in Link and Prepending before Navigation starts */
                                // $('html .mob-header').prependTo('.collapse.navbar-collapse');
                                /* Finding Mob Sign in Link and Prepending before Navigation ends */


                                /* Show right side Menu starts */

                                $('.mob-header').toggle();
                                $('.navbar-collapse').toggle('collapse');

                                //$('.mob-header').show();

                                var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

                                $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
                                    //right: selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
                                    right: selected ? navbarneg : '-15px'
                                });

                                $('#navbar-height-col, #page-content').stop().animate({
                                    right: selected ? navbarneg : '0px'
                                });

                                $('#page-content').stop().animate({
                                    right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
                                });

                                $('.navbar-header').stop().animate({
                                    right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
                                });

                                $('.score-footer').stop().animate({
                                    right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
                                });

                                $('.score-footer .container').stop().animate({
                                    right: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
                                });

                                $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);

                                $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active', 'fast');

                                //$('body, #page-content, .navbar,  .navbar-header, .score-footer, .score-footer .container').toggleClass('slide-active');
                                $('body, #page-content, .navbar,  .navbar-header, .score-footer, .score-footer').toggleClass('slide-active');

                                //$('.score-footer .container').hide();

                                //$('.slide-menu-content').toggle();

                                //$("body").append('<div class="back-drop" style="position: fixed;height: 100%;width: 100%;top: 0;right:83%;z-index: 990;"><\/div>');
                                navVisible == 0 ? (navVisible = 1,
                                    $("body").css("cursor", "pointer"),
                                    $("body").append('<div class="back-drop" style="position: fixed;height: 100%;width: 100%;top: 0;right:83%;z-index: 990;"><\/div>')) : (navVisible = 0,
                                        $("body").css("cursor", "inherit"),
                                        $(".back-drop").remove())
                                //: (navVisible = 0, $("body").css("cursor", "inherit"), $(".back-drop").remove()

                                /* Show right side Menu ends */
                            });

                            $(document).on('click', '.back-drop, #navbar-height-col', function () {
                                $('.navbar-toggle.slide-active').trigger('click');
                            })

                            /* Main Menu Button Hamburger ends */

                            /* Sub Menu starts */
                            $('.header-mega-menu a').click(function (e) {
                                if ($(this).hasClass('menu-links')) {

                                    if ($(this).hasClass('submenu-menu')) {
                                        $(this).removeClass('submenu-menu');
                                        $(this).next().next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                                        $(this).parents('.header-mega-menu').find('li').removeClass('open');
                                    } else {
                                        $('a.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('submenu-menu');
                                        $(this).parents('.header-mega-menu').find('li').removeClass('open');
                                        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                                        $(this).addClass('submenu-menu');
                                        $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                                        $(this).next().next('.dropdown-menu').show();
                                    }
                                }
                                if ($(this).hasClass('sub-menu-first-child')) {
                                    if ($(this).hasClass('submenu-menu')) {
                                        $(this).removeClass('submenu-menu');
                                        //$(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                                        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                                    } else {
                                        $('a.sub-menu-first-child').removeClass('submenu-menu');
                                        $(this).addClass('submenu-menu');
                                        $('.header-mega-menu-content').find('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                                        //$(this).parent().next('.dropdown-menu').show();
                                        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').show();
                                    }
                                }
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                            })
                            /* Sub Menu ends */
                        }

                        var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header, .score-footer';

                        $(window).on("resize", function () {
                            if ($(window).width() < 991 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
                                $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    promoBlockMatchHeight() {
                        $(".promo-match-height").each(function () {
                            var $promoleft = $(this).find(".score-left .caption");
                            var $promoRight = $(this).find(".score-right .caption");

                            $promoleft.height('');
                            $promoRight.height('');

                            var promoLeftHeight = $promoleft.innerHeight();
                            var promoRightHeight = $promoRight.innerHeight();

                            var heightVal = (promoLeftHeight == promoRightHeight) ? promoLeftHeight : promoRightHeight;

                            $promoleft.css({
                                "height": heightVal
                            });
                            $promoRight.css({
                                "height": heightVal
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    accordianList: function () {
                        $(".cate-navigator").find(".cat-nav-list-title").click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var $content = $(this).nextAll(".cat-nav-list");
                            $(".cate-navigator").find(".cat-nav-list").not($content).hide();
                            //$(this).nextAll(".cat-nav-list").toggle();
                            $(this).nextAll(".cat-nav-list").toggleClass('display-block');
                        });
                    },
                    init: function () {
                        PGBRAUN.domReady();
                        PGBRAUN.preventLinks();
                        PGBRAUN.megaMenuSP();
                        PGBRAUN.promoBlockMatchHeight();
                        PGBRAUN.accordianList();
                    }/*,
                    onWindowResizeRefresh: function () {
                        PGBRAUN.init();
                    }*/
                }
                return PGBRAUN.init();
            });
```

Comment: I did not understand when you want to refresh your functions?

Comment: do you want to call function toggleNavbarMethod() on resize the window?

Comment: @HardeepSingh : yes correct

Comment: @yoo: then it should already work, have you checked your browser console for any errors?

Comment: @HardeepSingh : i dont see any issues :-(

Comment: then the problem is with your code in the toggleNavbarMethod function for example you're binding mouseover event every time the width is > 1024, you should use unbind() function before that so it won't attach the same event to the same element X times you resize the window. If you provide the html code I can help you more.

Comment: @Fuross : Demo link - https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/uo34ddu6/

Comment: tell u later i too busy in office task

Comment: i test it my own mac there no any error and toggleNavbarMethod() triggering well. you can check window resize event working with console.log()

Comment: have u any other issue?. please explain breifly

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comments, you should use `unbind()` function before you add the *mouseover* event to your 'nav .score-megamenu-dropdown' element, so it won't bind the same event X times you resize the window.

```
function toggleNavbarMethod() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
        $('nav .score-megamenu-dropdown').unbind('mouseover'); // unbind the event
        $('nav .score-megamenu-dropdown').on('mouseover', function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
        }).on('mouseout', function () {
            $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click').blur();
        });
    }
    else {
        $('nav .score-megamenu-dropdown').off('mouseover').off('mouseout');
    }
}
```